# ANN prediction accuracy

Tags: r, regression, machine-learning, neural-networks, prediction

I'd like to discuss with you one thing, actually I'm confused. I'm trying to predict whether the tumor will metastasize in particular patient or not. We collected the data of ~60 patients and it looks like this:

```
df <- data.frame(gene_A = runif(5, 1.0, 10.0),
             gene_B = runif(5, 1.0, 10.0),
             gene_C = runif(5, 1.0, 10.0),
             gene_D = runif(5, 1.0, 10.0),
             metastasis = as.factor(sample(0:1, 5, replace=T)),
             organ_transplantation = as.factor(sample(0:1, 5, replace=T)),
             tumor_location = as.factor(sample(1:4, 5, replace=T)),
             age = sample(20:80, 5, replace=T),
             sex = as.factor(sample(0:1, 5, replace=T)),
             tumor_type = as.factor(sample(1:3, 5, replace=T)))

    gene_A   gene_B   gene_C   gene_D metastasis organ_transplantation tumor_location age sex tumor_type
1 1.488254 3.013757 5.084325 4.287109          0                     0              4  50   0          2
2 7.194623 9.493875 9.000487 6.395420          0                     0              1  73   0          2
3 3.167096 2.321673 2.934585 8.604870          1                     0              2  44   0          3
4 4.984675 3.730776 2.805044 6.526131          1                     0              2  48   0          2
5 1.613206 1.478562 1.838734 1.627630          0                     1              1  55   0          2
```

Where the values of genes represent normalized relative expression level (biomarkers), factors corresponding to binary variables such as `sex`, `organ_transplantation`. My dependent variable is `metastasis`. I converted the other qualitative, nominal variables to factors with several levels, e.g. `tumor_location` stomach, large intestine, small intestine, other to 1-4, I hope it's correct. Moreover it's only part of independent variables. My df has ~60 rows (patients) and 15 independent variables. As I read, the optimal proportion is 10 observations per one independent variable. Unfortunately I don't have enough observations.

Firstly I performed the logistic regression with all variables and it looks.... bad. I do not have statistical significance (pv<0.05 - Wald test) in any of my independent variables. In some cases I have pv<0.25, hence I consider these variables as variables significantly influencing the dependent variable (metastasis). Secondly I created several models only with one independent variable. Only some of them showed statistical significance... I decided to include them in the final model. The second problem is high collinearity of independent variables which I checked using `vif()` function. So I removed such variables. Finally from 15 independent variables I have 6. And they still don't look good regarding logistic regression (Wald's statistical significance). Nevertheless I decided to try this model out with the use of `predict()` function.
I choose two approaches: same model (same variables) obtained by `glm()` with `family = binomial(link="logit")`- logistic regression and `nnet()` - artificial neural networks.
I divided my data to train set (70%) and test set (30%) and run 1000 simulations of prediction:

```
sims_lr <- function(){
index <- sample(1:nrow(df),round(0.7*nrow(df)))
train <- df[index,]
test <- df[-index,]
model.train <- stats::glm(formula = metastasis ~ ., #selected independent variables
                          family = binomial(link="logit"), 
                          data = train, 
                          maxit = 50)
summary(model.train)
probabilities <- model.train %>% predict(test, type = "response")
predicted.classes <- ifelse(probabilities > 0.5, 1,0)
return(mean(predicted.classes == test$metastasis ))
}
k <- replicate(1000, sims_lr())
hist(k, labels = T,ylim=c(0,500), main='train 0.7 - 0.3 test')

sims_ann <- function(){ 
index <- sample(1:nrow(df),round(0.7*nrow(df)))
  train <- df[index,]
  test <- df[-index,]
mod <- nnet::nnet(metastasis ~., size = 10, linout = F, data = df, trace = FALSE, maxit=1000)#with selected variables and different parameters (nides and iterations)
ps <- predict(mod, test)
predicted.classes.nn <- ifelse(ps > 0.5, 1,0)
return(mean(predicted.classes.nn == test$metastasis ))
}
k <- replicate(1000, sims_ann())
hist(k, labels = T,ylim=c(0,500), main='train 0.7 - 0.3 test')
```

Here's the comparison:
[image]
As you see it doesn't look good... And I'm far from high prediction accuracy, nevertheless ANN worked better than logistic regression, hence I performed small experiment. I took the model with all variables and I performed 1000 prediction simulations using **ANN but with 90 nodes and 10000 iterations**. I took a while but result is as it should be...
[image]

I'm very confused because prediction is fine, but it's based on non-influencing variables (mostly). So if I put some totally not related variables (with cancer and metastasis) such as hair length, height, car colour etc. I'll have also nice prediction only because I increased number of nodes and iterations? That's why I'm sceptical regarding this machine leering approach... Could you please give me some advice and tell whether my reasoning is correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot make complete sense of you graphs. But generally speaking, good predictive power of a model does not necessarily have to results in "significant" predictors. The way I understand you confuse the significance with influence. But actually the significance cannot tell you something about the relevance of a predictor. Because your sample size is rather small for 15 independent variables (IV). It is not surprise that you will not find many significant effects. To asses whether a variable has some relevance to the prediction you could look at the varaince that is explained by each of the IVs.

What I would suggest to try would be to see if a random forest model works better. ANNs are hard to train, especially with so little data. Pus you can get a ranking of most mimportant variables